# Filter queryset inside a form

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have one app that holds a list of work orders, and another app that holds list of parts.

```
class Order(models.Model):
  parts = models.ManyToManyField(Part, blank=True) # Assosiated parts

class Part(models.Model):
  partnum = models.CharField(max_length=20) # Part number
  mwos = models.ManyToManyField('mtn.Order', blank=True) # Assosiated work orders
```

Now i want to add a button to my `DetailView` for order which will open a list of parts, which i will be able to add to my order. At the moment i have a created an `UpdateView` for my order

```
class AddPartView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, UpdateView):   
    model = Order
    form_class = AddPartForm
    ...
```

and a form

```
class AddPartForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ['parts', ]
        labels = {'parts': "Parts", }

    def FilterList(request):
        qs = Part.objects.all()
        search_part_query = request.GET.get('search_part')

        if is_valid_queryparam(search_part_query):
            qs = qs.filter(Q(partnum__icontains=search_part_query) 
                | Q(descr__icontains=search_part_query)
                ).distinct()

        return qs         

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        super(AddPartForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields["parts"].widget = CheckboxSelectMultiple()
        self.fields["parts"].queryset = self.FilterList()
```

for this template

```
{% block content %}

  <form method="GET" action=".">
    <div class="form-row justify-content-start">
      <div class="form-group col-md align-self-center">
        <div class="input-group">
          <input class="form-conrol py-2 border-right-0 border" type="search" placeholder="Find part" name="search_part">
            <span class="input-group-append">
              <div class="input-group-text bg-transparent">
                <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
              </div>
            </span>                      
        </div>
      </div>            
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-block">Search</button>    
  </form>

  <form action="{% url 'mtn:add_part' order.id %}" method='post'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}  
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
  </form>

{% endblock content %}
```

But when i'm executing it i get
`'AddPartForm' object has no attribute 'GET'`
error.

I am new to programming, so maybe i am approaching this the wrong way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A form is normally *not* aware of the `request` object. You can make such a form, for example with:

```
class AddPartForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ['parts', ]
        labels = {'parts': "Parts", }
        widgets = {
            'parts': CheckboxSelectMultiple
        }

    def filter_list(self, request):
        qs = Part.objects.all()
        search_part_query = request.GET.get('search_part')

        if is_valid_queryparam(search_part_query):
            qs = qs.filter(Q(partnum__icontains=search_part_query) 
                | Q(descr__icontains=search_part_query)
                ).distinct()

        return qs         

    def __init__(self, *args, request=None, **kwargs):
        super(AddPartForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["parts"].queryset = self.filter_list(request)
```

In the `AddPartView`, you can the pass the `request` as parameter to the form by overriding the [**`.get_form_kwargs(..)`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.get_form_kwargs)

```
class AddPartView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, UpdateView):   
    model = Order
    form_class = AddPartForm

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs.update(request=self.request)
        return kwargs
```